# Installing LaserFiche with PowerShell and Chocolatey

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm building a custom Chocolatey repo with custom packages for my organization so that we can easily manage software without Group Policies. One piece of software we use is LaserFiche. I am trying to make it do a silent installation, however every time I install from my Choco package, it says that it couldn't install MSXML 6 SP1. All the other prerequisites are installed successfully. I was thinking it was an issue with the installer not being able to find the .msi associated with this, but I tried manually running the installer for that add-on and then installing from my package and it still failed. I'm quite confused as to what is wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to ensure you are using Install-ChocolateyINSTALLPackage as opposed to Install-ChocolateyPackage if you are using an MSI that has CABs or other files next to it. The latter command will copy the MSI to a different location (and not other required files) and run the install from there. This is all documented in `choco new laserfiche` if you are on newer versions of Chocolatey.

Comment: Another thing, Chocolatey Business customers do have the option to engage with our packaging support services to handle particularly troublesome installers. It's something else to consider should you run into too much trouble.